# File not found on pythonanywhere.com

Tags: django, python-3.x, pythonanywhere

On [pythonanywhere.com](https://www.pythonanywhere.com) I have a django app. This is `views.py`:

```
def literature(request):
    module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, 'literature.csv')
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        ...
```

File `literature.csv` is located at the same directory as views.py. But every time when I try to load the page I get `FileNotFoundError`. The same construction works normally on local server. Where is the bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `os.path.dirname(__file__)` is giving you a relative path. On your local server, it just happens that it corresponds to the correct path. On PythonAnywhere, use the full path for `module_dir`. Like this: `os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))`