# File not found in app hosted in pythonanywhere

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

There is an answer here - [File not found on pythonanywhere.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32329216/file-not-found-on-pythonanywhere-com)

But it doesn't work in my case.

I have put the file in both the project main directory and the `/project/static` directory -

[image: In main directory]

[image: In Static directory]

My code -

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
from diffdiag import DifferentialDiagScript2 as dd
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

@app.route('/')
@cross_origin()
def index():
    module_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    file_path = os.path.join(module_dir, 'literature.csv')
    items = list(line.strip() for line in open(file_path))
    return render_template('index.html', table = items)
```

I have also tried -

```
items = list(line.strip() for line in open(f2))

items = list(line.strip() for line in open('./static/f2'))

items = list(line.strip() for line in open('/home/daddyodevil/add/Automated_DD/f2'))

items = list(line.strip() for line in open('/home/daddyodevil/add/Automated_DD/static/f2'))
```

Nothing seems to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Edit 1 - Adding complete error

```
Exception on / [GET]#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/home/daddyodevil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app#012    response = self.full_dispatch_request()#012  File "/home/daddyodevil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request#012    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)#012  File "/home/daddyodevil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 161, in wrapped_function#012    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))#012  File "/home/daddyodevil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception#012    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)#012  File "/home/daddyodevil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise#012    raise value#012  File "/home/daddyodevil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request#012    rv = self.dispatch_request()#012  File "/home/daddyodevil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request#012    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)#012  File "/home/daddyodevil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_cors/decorator.py", line 128, in wrapped_function#012    resp = make_response(f(*args, **kwargs))#012  File "/home/daddyodevil/add/Automated_DD/app.py", line 13, in index#012    items = list(line.strip() for line in open("./static/f2"))#012FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './static/f2'
```

Edit 2 - Adding error received when trying to run `app.py` in pythonanywhere

```
 * Serving Flask app "app" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/daddyodevil/add/Automated_DD/app.py", line 47, in <module>
    app.run()
  File "/home/daddyodevil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 943, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/home/daddyodevil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 814, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/home/daddyodevil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 774, in inner
    fd=fd)
  File "/home/daddyodevil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 660, in make_server
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
  File "/home/daddyodevil/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 577, in __init__
    self.address_family), handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/server.py", line 136, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socketserver.py", line 467, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? can you paste it here?

Comment: @Mufeed, Did it.

Answer (score 3):

Running app.py in a PythonAnywhere console is unlikely to work -- it will try to bind to a port and listen for connections, and it's entirely possible that someone else is using the port.

The problem you're seeing in your website error log is because you're trying to open the file `'./static/f2'`.   This path with be resolved relative to the directory where the application is running, which is not necessarily the same as the directory containing the module, and might not be the main directory either.

If you want to load up the one in the same directory as the module, and you already have code to work out the module directory like this

```
module_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

...then you can change your code to use that `module_dir` by changing the line

```
items = list(line.strip() for line in open("./static/f2"))
```

...to be this:

```
items = list(line.strip() for line in open(os.path.join(module_dir, "./static/f2")))
```

Answer (score 0):

The linked answer doesn't work for you because you haven't followed it properly. Wrap your module directory inside `os.path.abspath()` in order to get the absolute path as the linked answer suggests:

```
module_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

**Edit**

Also ensure that this file actually exists relative to your module directory:

```
'./static/f2'
```

Because that's where the exception is being thrown (look at the last line of the stack trace):

```
items = list(line.strip() for line in open("./static/f2"))
#012FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './static/f2'
```

Comment: Yeti, It didn't work and also if you see the images I attached, it can be seen that the file f2 is in both the main / directory as well as in /static/ directory.

Comment: I see that you've edited now with a different error message than before (`OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use`). Does this mean that the old error stopped coming after you made this change ?

Comment: No, the old error remains when I try to go to daddyodevil.pythonanywhere.com and present in the error logs. 5he new error that I added to the post is the one I am getting when I try to 'run' app.py in python anywhere console.